# Error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save() laravel

Tags: laravel

nuevamente acudo a todos a ver si me pueden orientar un poco en lo siguiente: tengo una vista en la cual tengo una tabla con una serie de inputs radio a los cuales les cargo el valor que traen desde la base de datos, hasta ahí me funciona impecable pero ahora necesito implementar la funcionalidad de actualizar los valores, es decir que el usuario pueda cambiar los valores de los inputs... Estuve haciendo pruebas pero en todas me lanza el error: **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()**

Basicamente en el controlador tengo el metodo asi:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

        //return $request->all();

        $ejecucion = EjecucionMantenimiento::find($id);
        $mantenimientoCaracteristica = MantenimientoCaracteristica::where('ejecucion_mantenimiento_id', $id);

        //return $mantenimientoCaracteristica;

        //Modifica los valores en la tabla mantenimiento_caracteristicas
         if ( $request->has('car') ) {
            foreach ( $request->get('car') as $key => $caracteristica ) {
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas = $mantenimientoCaracteristica;
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->caracteristica_id = $key;
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->opcion = $caracteristica;
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->observaciones = $request->get('carobs')[$key];
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->ejecucion_mantenimiento_id = $ejecucion->id;
                $MantenimientoCaracteristicas->save();
            }
        }
```

$mantenimientoCaracteristica es la variable donde tengo los resultados de los inputs (que estan almacenados en una tabla de la bd con el id_mantencion que vincula con una tabla padre llamada mantenimiento)...

La duda que tengo es como tendria que hacer para hacer una actualizacion y no un nuevo insert

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0):

```
$mantenimientoCaracteristica = MantenimientoCaracteristica::where('ejecucion_mantenimiento_id', $id)->first();
```

Falta apuntar al método ->first()

Comment: Mmm pero con el.first traería solo el primer registro, en este caso son 12 filas con el mismo.id se mantenimiento pero los input radio tienen un ID casa uno